# Flutter CameraException: CameraException(Error -11803, AVFoundationErrorDomain)

Tags: flutter, camera

I'm getting this error for camera package of flutter, I'm not sure how to handle this.
I can't find the error codes of the camera package.

```
    CameraException: CameraException(Error -11803, AVFoundationErrorDomain)
  File "camera.dart", line 302, in CameraController.takePicture
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "take_picture.dart", line 120, in _TakePictureState._takePicture
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "take_picture.dart", line 89, in _TakePictureState._onPressTakePicture
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "take_picture.dart", line 48, in _TakePictureState.build.<fn>
  File "ink_well.dart", line 654, in _InkResponseState._handleTap
  File "ink_well.dart", line 729, in _InkResponseState.build.<fn>
  File "recognizer.dart", line 182, in GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
  File "tap.dart", line 365, in TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
  File "tap.dart", line 275, in TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
  File "recognizer.dart", line 455, in PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
  File "pointer_router.dart", line 75, in PointerRouter._dispatch
  File "pointer_router.dart", line 102, in PointerRouter.route
  File "binding.dart", line 218, in GestureBinding.handleEvent
  File "binding.dart", line 198, in GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
  File "binding.dart", line 156, in GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent
  File "binding.dart", line 102, in GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
  File "binding.dart", line 86, in GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
  File "zone.dart", line 1136, in _rootRunUnary
  File "zone.dart", line 1029, in _CustomZone.runUnary
  File "zone.dart", line 931, in _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
  File "hooks.dart", line 263, in _invoke1
  File "hooks.dart", line 172, in _dispatchPointerDataPacket
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using image_picker plugin.
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker